# libGDX AdMob in Android?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I followed this tutorial (second link “replaces deprecated AdMob”. For some reason I can’t post it properly) to implement AdMob in my libGDX game:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Mobile-Ads-in-Libgdx-(replaces-deprecated-AdMob)

Banner Code:
https://github.com/TheInvader360/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads/blob/9a4c9342d98c02e3c44e0b62fcfaa153d257130a/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads-android/src/com/theinvader360/tutorial/libgdx/google/ads/MainActivity.java

Can someone check the code and tell me which changes I need to do to implement my own banner?
What I’ve done so far:
1. In “AD_UNIT_ID” I wrote the code that I got when I created the banner for my App.
2. In “GOOGLE_PLAY_URL” I wrote my developer name.
I checked the app on my device and everything worked fine. Yet what I worry about is:
1. If someone from around the world will download my App will he\she see relevant ads for their location?
2. All I see in my banner are text ads, not exactly the most interesting to tap. How can I put more interesting ads? I mean, when playing Angry Birds I see different games ads, even those of other companies like SUPERCELL…
3. By following the code above the banner appear at the top of the screen and remain there without disappearing. How can I limit the banner view time to appear and disappear every certain amount of seconds by the code above?
4. My game runs on different states (state menu, state running, state pause, state game over…). How can I make the banner appear at the top of the screen in one state and at the bottom at another?
I know this post might be too much, but please guide me through this last step of my first App.